# Contact Form 7 - Wordpress - Select Default from <select> Dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form that I built using "Contact Form 7" plugin for my WordPress powered website. In that form I have a dropdown select field.

```
[select menu-214 "Red" "Green" "Orange" "Purple"]
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to select a default from those four colors based on the url query that is used to access the page.

http://example.com/contact/?color=Purple

or something like that would choose the default value for the contact form's select field as "Purple"

Answer (score 2):

After Googling around, I found [this post from 2011](http://www.featheredowl.com/contact-form-7-default-select-value-url-query-variable/#comment-8005) and it still works.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer